# For a given condition, get indices of values in 2D tensor A, use those to index a 3D tensor B

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, pytorch, tensor, tensor-indexing

For a given 2D tensor I want to retrieve all indices where the value is `1`. I expected to be able to simply use `torch.nonzero(a == 1).squeeze()`, which would return `tensor([1, 3, 2])`. However, instead, `torch.nonzero(a == 1)` returns a 2D tensor (that's okay), with two values per row (that's not what I expected). The returned indices should then be used to index the second dimension (index 1) of a 3D tensor, again returning a 2D tensor.

```py
import torch

a = torch.Tensor([[12, 1, 0, 0],
                  [4, 9, 21, 1],
                  [10, 2, 1, 0]])

b = torch.rand(3, 4, 8)

print('a_size', a.size())
# a_size torch.Size([3, 4])
print('b_size', b.size())
# b_size torch.Size([3, 4, 8])

idxs = torch.nonzero(a == 1)
print('idxs_size', idxs.size())
# idxs_size torch.Size([3, 2])

print(b.gather(1, idxs))
```

Evidently, this does not work, leading to aRunTimeError:

> RuntimeError: invalid argument 4: Index tensor must have same
>   dimensions as input tensor at
>   C:\w\1\s\windows\pytorch\aten\src\TH/generic/THTensorEvenMoreMath.cpp:453

It seems that `idxs` is not what I expect it to be, nor can I use it the way I thought. `idxs` is

```
tensor([[0, 1],
        [1, 3],
        [2, 2]])
```

but reading through the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.nonzero) I don't understand why I also get back the row indices in the resulting tensor. Now, I know I can get the correct idxs by slicing `idxs[:, 1]` but then still, I cannot use those values as indices for the 3D tensor because the same error as before is raised. Is it possible to use the 1D tensor of indices to select items across a given dimension?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply slice them and pass it as the indices as in:

```
In [193]: idxs = torch.nonzero(a == 1)     
In [194]: c = b[idxs[:, 0], idxs[:, 1]]  

In [195]: c   
Out[195]: 
tensor([[0.3411, 0.3944, 0.8108, 0.3986, 0.3917, 0.1176, 0.6252, 0.4885],
        [0.5698, 0.3140, 0.6525, 0.7724, 0.3751, 0.3376, 0.5425, 0.1062],
        [0.7780, 0.4572, 0.5645, 0.5759, 0.5957, 0.2750, 0.6429, 0.1029]])
```

---

Alternatively, an even simpler & my preferred approach would be to just use [`torch.where()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.where) and then directly index into the tensor `b` as in:

```
In [196]: b[torch.where(a == 1)]  
Out[196]: 
tensor([[0.3411, 0.3944, 0.8108, 0.3986, 0.3917, 0.1176, 0.6252, 0.4885],
        [0.5698, 0.3140, 0.6525, 0.7724, 0.3751, 0.3376, 0.5425, 0.1062],
        [0.7780, 0.4572, 0.5645, 0.5759, 0.5957, 0.2750, 0.6429, 0.1029]])
```

A bit more explanation about the above approach of using `torch.where()`: It works based on the concept of [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). That is, when we index into the tensor using a tuple of sequence objects such as tuple of tensors, tuple of lists, tuple of tuples etc.

```
# some input tensor
In [207]: a  
Out[207]: 
tensor([[12.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
        [ 4.,  9., 21.,  1.],
        [10.,  2.,  1.,  0.]])
```

For basic slicing, we would need a tuple of integer indices:

```
   In [212]: a[(1, 2)] 
   Out[212]: tensor(21.)
```

To achieve the same using advanced indexing, we would need a tuple of sequence objects:

```
# adv. indexing using a tuple of lists
In [213]: a[([1,], [2,])] 
Out[213]: tensor([21.])

# adv. indexing using a tuple of tuples
In [215]: a[((1,), (2,))]  
Out[215]: tensor([21.])

# adv. indexing using a tuple of tensors
In [214]: a[(torch.tensor([1,]), torch.tensor([2,]))] 
Out[214]: tensor([21.])
```

And the dimension of the returned tensor would always be one dimension less than the dimension of the input tensor.

Comment: I very much love the simplicity of your second suggestion. Could you explain a bit more *why* this works? Since `torch.where(a == 1)` returns a tuple. How does slicing a tensor with a tuple work like that?

Comment: @BramVanroy added some explanation  :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `b`'s three dimensions are `batch_size x sequence_length x features` (b x s x feats), the expected results can be achieved as follows.

```py
import torch

a = torch.Tensor([[12, 1, 0, 0],
                  [4, 9, 21, 1],
                  [10, 2, 1, 0]])

b = torch.rand(3, 4, 8)
print(b.size())
# b x s x feats
idxs = torch.nonzero(a == 1)[:, 1]
print(idxs.size())
# b
c = b[torch.arange(b.size(0)), idxs]
print(c.size())
# b x feats
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import torch

a = torch.Tensor([[12, 1, 0, 0],
                  [4, 9, 21, 1],
                  [10, 2, 1, 0]])

b = torch.rand(3, 4, 8)

print('a_size', a.size())
# a_size torch.Size([3, 4])
print('b_size', b.size())
# b_size torch.Size([3, 4, 8])

#idxs = torch.nonzero(a == 1, as_tuple=True)
idxs = torch.nonzero(a == 1)
#print('idxs_size', idxs.size())

print(torch.index_select(b,1,idxs[:,1]))
```

Comment: No, not at all. First of all `z` is a tuple, second my final goal is to get an index from `b`.

Comment: yeah sorry I completely didn't read your question correctly...for your final question "Is it possible to use the 1D tensor of indices to select items across a given dimension", ,does torch.index_select(b,1,idxs[:,1]) give you what you need?

Comment: No. That'll return a 3D matrix. I expect a 2D one. See my answer.

Comment: ah, gotcha.  glad you figured it out.  sidenote just make sure there aren't 2 1's in a row

Answer (score 0):

As a supplementary of @kmario23's solution, you can still achieve the same results like

```py
b[torch.nonzero(a==1,as_tuple=True)]
```